# Recursive Adapter for Tree

Tags: java, gson

I have a special use case for gson.
I have the following structure:

```
public abstract class BaseNode {
    BaseNode left;
    BaseNode right;
}

public class DerivedNode extends BaseNode {
    int val;
}
```

As you can see this is a binary tree, and I want to apply an adapter for all the nodes in the tree so that I can deserialize them as DerivedNode, not BaseNode, otherwise it will throw unable to instantiate an abstract class. Currently what I do is:

```
...
Gson gson = new new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(BaseNode.class, new 
     TypeAdapter<ObjectBasedPermission>() {
        @Override
          public void write(JsonWriter out, ObjectBasedPermission value) throws IOException {}

          @Override
          @SuppressWarnings("ALL")
          public ObjectBasedPermission read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
            return gson.fromJson(in, DerivedNode);
          }
     }}).create();
```

My question is can I do this? Is this safe? Will the future update of gson affect this code snippet?

Comment: Could you please check your code snippet again? It contains a few syntax errors and refers to `ObjectBasedPermission` which is not mentioned anywhere else in your question. Additionally, why is the `write` method empty? If you don't intend it to be called, then throw an exception there. Maybe you could simply register an [`InstanceCreator`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/InstanceCreator.html) for `BaseNode` which creates `DerivedNode` instances (which are then populated by Gson's reflection-based adapter).

Comment: sry I didnt notice that, and actually I think InstanceCreator is the answer I am looking for, thx!

Answer (score 0):

To anyone with same problem, InstanceCreator solves my problem